# Binding window location not working two way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to persist the location of a window, I have the following XAML (non-relevant parts removed)

```
<Window x:Class="App.MainWindow"
  Title="MainWindow" Name="mainWindow"
  Top="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.PositionY}"
  Left="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.PositionX}"
  AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
  Background="#01000000" Topmost="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.AlwaysOnTop}"
   MouseLeftButtonDown="mainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown"
```

"Settings" is defined in App.xaml and maps to the app settings

A search on Google gives several examples of this using exactly the method I have used.

The binding of TopMost works exactly as expected, this value is persisted between runs
The binding of Top and Left however only appears to work one way.  The window picks up its location from the setting correctly but when moved, the settings are not updated.
A breakpoint on my Settings.Save function shows that the Top and Left properties have changed as expected.  Manually copying these values into the settings just before save works fine.
I have tried explicitly specifying Mode=TwoWay to no effect (should be default anyway)

PositionX and PositionY are both user settings defined as type double

Moving the window is accomplished with the following mouse handler

```
private void mainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
  DragMove();
}
```

Any ideas why the two way binding only works one way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it really doesn't work without explicitly setting TwoWay. I just tried this:

```
Top="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.PositionY, Mode=TwoWay}" 
Left="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.PositionX, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and that does the job.

Concerning INotifyPropertyChanged: that's not necessary because it's the other binding direction, i.e. the one that works once on startup. And it's possibly hard to implement in a generated class.

Comment: Doh! - The "TopMost" binding appeared to work TwoWay but now I suspect I had other code that made it look like it worked.  Adding TwoWay didn't fix it first time round but again, that pesky "other code" may have nobbled it

Answer (score 1):

What ColinE said: Make your you implement the `INotofiyPropertyChanged` interface correctly. It would help if you'd share the code of your Settings-class with us.

BUT also make sure that you specify your Binding Mode `Mode=TwoWay`, which is NOT the default as you suggest in your question.

Comment: I'm using a VS generated settings class that does implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

In order for the bindings to update, the object that exposes the `PositionY` and `PositionX` properties needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when these two properties change. You haven't shown this part of your code, but my guess is that you are not doing this.